# Traveling to Taiwan for Mainland Chinese - visa requirements?

Tags: visas, taiwan, chinese-citizens

My girlfriend is from Mainland China, and we would like to travel to China together. However, as we understand, the requirement for Chinese is to travel in a tour group if they want to go to Taiwan.

Is there a way around this? Is there any we that we could travel, just the two of us, from China to Taiwan, without being in a tour group?

Comment: related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62447/how-can-a-citizen-of-mainland-china-visit-taiwan/62466#comment178495_62466https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62447/how-can-a-citizen-of-mainland-china-visit-taiwan/62466#comment178495_62466

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, last year they started allowing solo Chinese travelers. I met a Chinese backpacker who was not part of a tour group last July. This is a hard one to understand as my Mandarin is mediocre at best. For Taiwanese going to China, they need to go to the Taiwan Immigration Bureau in Taipei, I don't know about the other way around. I know this isn't horribly helpful, but I DO know that there were some Chinese backpackers here last year, but I also know it isn't that common. I would recommend visiting whichever bureau dispenses visas to Taiwan and ask them.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where your girlfriend lives in. I know that from last year, the resident in Beijing, Shanghai, and Xiamen can apply for visa to Taiwan for personal traveling. And it seems that more cities are available in this year.

Comment: Could you supply some reference for that info ?