# Can a Chinese citizen living in Europe go to Taiwan?

Tags: international-travel, europe, china, taiwan, chinese-citizens

## Context

My girlfriend is a Chinese (PRC) citizen and we are now living in central Europe. I went to Taiwan with a friend two years ago and really enjoyed it, and my girlfriend and I would  like to go there together as tourists.

However, since 2019 [China bans Chinese citizens from traveling to Taiwan without a group](https://time.com/5639832/china-bans-travel-taiwan-tourists/). We are not interested in a group trip.

## Question

Does this ban also concern Chinese citizens living abroad ? If not, how should we proceed to get there, and how easy/risky would that be for her (e.g., issue at Taipei airport, further issue when she goes back to Mainland at some point, etc.) ?

I found [this Q/A](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62447/how-can-a-citizen-of-mainland-china-visit-taiwan), but as it was asked in 2016, it's likely not accurate with the 2019 change.

## Notes

- For this question, please assume that there is no Covid-19 crisis, as it's not really the problem I'm interested in
- Whatever we do, this has to be legal for both of us, the goal is not to cheat on Chinese authorities

Comment: This is really a matter that you should ask your responsible consulate about. That is what they are there for.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That's terrible advice and hardly what consulates are for, I don't get why you keep making similar comments on numerous questions. You don't want to attract attention to yourself if what you are contemplating is against the rules (or, sometimes, even if it is formally legal but frowned upon, especially in a country like the PRC).

Comment: Even if something is within your rights and you're dealing with a more permissive country, it's not uncommon for consulates to be difficult to reach, to give misleading advice or to deny visas unlawfully. For all these reasons, it's important to have a clear idea of your legal position, how to best make your case, and whether or how to push back against what a consulate might tell you before approaching them.

Comment: @Relaxed Sorry, but you obviously don't have the faintest clue how these things work. The Chinese consulate is the **only** authority that can start an authorization process if it is possible when residing outside of China. As a Chinese citizen the OP should ask nowhere else. The OP has made it **very clear** that they wish to do this in a straight forward legal way. For that, there is only 1 way: through the proper authority. This was also true in the last 3 decades of East- Block countries,  that I have had personal experience with, whos travel regime was far stricter than China's.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I have the feeling you're the one who has no practical experience with this. Obviously, the consulate is the only *authority* that can take this decision (or more generally issue visas, etc.) but approaching it to get legal advice as you so often suggest is counter-productive. You should only contact it once you have a clear idea or independent advice on whether something is legal and achievable, what is required, how to best present your case, etc. That's not even specific to consulates or travel matters, that's how you should go about any consequential legal matter.

Comment: And if you know this to be legal, what the actual procedure is and that it has a realistic chance of success, then that's the answer the OP is seeking and you should detail that in an answer. But suggesting that he (or anybody else) should “ask“ consulates whether that's the case is still unhelpful. It's precisely *because the consulate is the only authority that can start the process* that you should not approach it mindlessly with open-ended questions or to see what sticks.

Comment: @Relaxed Both of your assumptions are false. Also your assumptions about the function of a consulate is lopsided. Of the 13 defined functions, most of which with deal with the intersest of their citizens (legal, administrative and protection matters), point (d) is the issuing passports of travel documents to their citizens **and** issuing of visas. In a matter such as this (ever evolving), the OP should undertake nothing without first consulting their consulate.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Which assumptions now? What do you suppose I suggested the OP should undertake without first consulting their consulate? The only things I mentioned are informing yourself and getting legal advice ; are you seriously suggesting one should contact their consulate before doing that?

Comment: @MarkJohnson Thank you for you advice. While I have slightly more trust than the average westerner in PRC, I'd still prefer to know more about this matter before to reach any official institution. This is likely a further step in the process, but right now I'd rather have either an external assessment about those questions, or a clear sourced answer about the feasibility and/or consequences. I want to do it in the most legal way, but I'd like to avoid drawing unnecessary attention as well. We never know.

Comment: @Tim As you are probably aware of, the truth of today is not necessarily the truth of yesterday nor the truth of tomorrow. Some topics are very sensitive. I don't think any 3rd party can give a reliable answer to this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The suspension only concerns the issuance of the Two-way Travel Pass to Taiwan with G endorsement (private tourism) for Mainland residents (**including those abroad on tourist visas**, but not for people living abroad on student visa valid longer than a year or with a residence permit). The G endorsement was on a pilot run only for residents in certain cities; PRC passport holders abroad are not eligible to apply.

The use of the two-way pass was never required if you are not flying from (**and not flying back to**) or transiting in Mainland (not including HK/Macau), where the exit immigration control does not accept anything but a validly endorsed Travel Pass or Mainland Travel Permit for Taiwan Residents, in accordance to the One China principle.

The restrictions (Travel Pass, Exit/Entry permit etc.) are based on bilateral agreements on exchange of residents on different sides, usually do not concern expats abroad for either side.

You only need a passport (with more than six months validity remaining) and the electronic Exit/Entry permit from Taiwan authorities.

If you ask the PRC consulate, they'll be put in an awkward position and probably won't answer your question directly. The Taiwanese representation will inform you of the necessary procedures, and presumably would also warn you if they are aware of any problems.

Unless you are in a politically sensitive political/military position, or a political dissident (for whom it doesn't really matter since you wouldn't be able to return to Mainland trouble-free anyway), the Mainland government more or less doesn't care if you go to Taiwan or not if you are not resident.

See the guides updated after the suspension for Chinese abroad (in Chinese)

1. https://www.uscreditcardguide.com/daluquxiaodatongzhenggqianzhichangjianwentiwendajiyuce/
2. https://www.pekflyer.com/%E5%A4%A7%E9%99%86%E8%B5%B4%E5%8F%B0%E8%87%AA%E7%94%B1%E8%A1%8C%E8%A2%AB%E5%8F%AB%E5%81%9C%EF%BC%8C%E6%B5%B7%E5%A4%96%E6%8C%81%E5%AD%A6-%E5%B7%A5%E7%AD%BE%E6%9A%82%E6%97%A0%E5%BD%B1%E5%93%8D/

---

> 第二条　居住在大陆的中国公民（以下简称大陆居民）往来台湾地区（以下简称台湾）以及居住在台湾地区的中国公民（以下简称台湾居民）来往大陆，适用本办法。
>
> Article 2 These measures apply to Chinese citizens **residing on the mainland** (hereinafter referred to as mainland residents) to travel to and from Taiwan regions (hereinafter referred to as Taiwan) and Chinese citizens residing in Taiwan regions (hereinafter referred to as Taiwan residents) to travel to and from the mainland.
>
> Measures for Chinese citizens to travel to and from Taiwan: http://www.gqb.gov.cn/news/2019/0604/46255.shtml

Comment: Thank you a thousand times! Very complete and straightforward answer.